# Cronjob for different environments

Tags: cron, solaris

I have a script which is to be run on different environments using a cronjob on Solaris.How do I set the environment variables for each environment before the cronjob. I tried by initilizing the specific env. variables before each cronjob but it did not workout. Can anyone give a way to do this ?

Comment: Please show us exactly what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign environment variables directly in the crontab, just add a line

VAR=value

That will take effect for all cron jobs for that user on that machine.

Or is that what you tried? I'm not sure what happens if you try to assign the same variable more than once, my guess would be that only the last one will have effect.

Comment: I tried that by assigning the variables just before the cronjob and gave a time interval between all the jobs of different environment, But it didn't work for me.I did the same thing for linux it worked fine but the same is not working in Solaris

Answer (score 0):

You can export the vars you like in the cron or source a file with several settings. The next 4 crontab entries use different environment settings.

```
10 * * * * export ONEVAR=firstExample; myscript >/dev/null 2>&1
20 * * * * export ONEVAR=secondExample; myscript >/dev/null 2>&1
30 * * * * . /home/user2262977/settings3; myscript >/dev/null 2>&1
40 * * * * . /home/user2262977/settings4; myscript >/dev/null 2>&1
```

EDIT
Another solution is using a parameter in your script (or a wrapper script calling your script). Crontab would look like

```
10 * * * * /home/user2262977/myscript settings1 >/dev/null 2>&1
20 * * * * /home/user2262977/myscript settings2 >/dev/null 2>&1
30 * * * * /home/user2262977/myscript settings3 >/dev/null 2>&1
40 * * * * /home/user2262977/myscript settings4 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and your script will start with

```
case $1 in
"settings1")
   ONEVAR=firstExample
   SECONDVAR=firstSomething
   SERVER=firstServer
   ;;
"settings2")
   ONEVAR=secondExample
   SECONDVAR=secondSomething
   SERVER=secondServer
   ;;
"settings3")
   ONEVAR=thirdExample
   SECONDVAR=thirdSomething
   SERVER=thirdServer
   ;;
"settings4")
   ONEVAR=somethingCompletelyDifferent
   SECONDVAR=didntExpectThisOneComing
   SERVER=stackoverflow.com
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: I have tried the same created a file conataining all the environment variables and added to the cronjob just before the script is run but still it did not work for me.Actually I am running a script on database server which connects as SYSDBA for various instances present on the database server .Anything else that could be done ?That would be a great help

Comment: Can you show your crontab line(s) ? The settings must be done in the line as the call to your script and must be sourced with a dot. When you need ksh, say so in the shebang line of the script or in the call to myscript

Comment: What do you mean by "added to the crontab just before the script is run"? It will not work to have one cron job just setting variables and another one running the script. Each cron job is completely independent and starts with a minimal environment. If you need different value for a variable for each instance, I'd suggest passing it as an argument to the script instead.

Comment: I do not understand your comment `added to the cronjob just before the script is run`, I was afraid you have 2 different crontabs. The second will know nothing from the first, they are completely independent. Another solution: see EDIT.

Comment: I wrote the crontab in the following format:
* * * * * . / (Path of the file containing environment variables) ; . (The script which I have to  run)

Comment: @WalterA  and Bjorn Munch I have not written two crontabs (one for environment variables and other to run the script) rather I wrote it in the format mentioned in the above comment, but still it is not working for me . Thanks

Comment: Start testing the crontab / variables with little test scripts. First `* * * * * ls myfile > /tmp/crontest` and `* * * * * . /your/path/yoursettings; set > /tmp/crontest`.